# flash cs5 packages can't be nested issue

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash

So I am working on an app and I am getting a "packages cannot be nested" error when I try to run.  There are no errors in the syntax that flash told me.

Code -

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class main extends MovieClip {
        public function main() {
            init()
        }
        private function init():void
        {
            home_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleButtonClicks);
        }

        private function handleButtonClicks():void
        {
            stop();
            gotoAndStop("home_page");

        }
    }


}
```

Thanks

Comment: Need more context.  The code is fine  (though you could use a semicolor after `init()`).  What's the name of your .as file for this class? (main.as I hope, and in the root folder of your project) Do you have another main class defined somewhere?  are you accidentally using the `include` keyword instead of `import` when referencing this class?

Comment: figured it out I needed to not associate the .as inside the actual timeline...forgot but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Old thread (month ago), i know.

I guess your code is in de fla (not an external as file).
Simply remove the word Package and it parenthesis (package {}) and run again.
This will work, guaranteed.

And also it is possible that flash gives an error about scope declarations like 'public', 'private' etc, remove also these.